# Unloading silverlight projects on Visual Studio 2012

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, silverlight, visual-studio-2012

Opening My solution in visual studio 2012, I want to Build and then Unload projects that I don't need, As I always did in vs 2010.

Strangely, every time I Unload Silverlight Projects, builded xaps, disappear from the ASP .NET project that is hosting them.
Thus it's required that I reload all projects of the solution to find xaps at Runtime.

Am i missing an information regarding migration of visual studio 2010 sln to 2012 ?

Comment: To be clear, I have many solution' folders in which I have my Silverlight apps. to Accelerate build time, I usually build the whole solution for first time, then unload all folders except the ones on which I work. the xaps disappear when I launch the web application.

Comment: I ve added  Bug on Microsoft Connect : https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/786544/visual-studio-2012-cleans-up-automatically-generated-xap

Answer (score 0):

In web project properties the location defined as shown below. When you unload project can't build and clean after clean directory works. 
Just put your xap somewhere else.

[image]

Comment: here few comments: - I am using the same solution since 2 years in VS 2010 and it works fine;  - the problem appeared only when migrating to vs 2012 ;  - I have not Cleaned any of the projects

Comment: It means it is changed for VS2012, it looks for related sl projects from the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of unloading for gaining build time why not let visual studio skip them at build via toolbar Build -> Configuration Manager -> Uncheck projects you want to skip.

Comment: good idea, but not viable within Team of 12 developers, where each dev, work on subset of solution. Note that if you make such modifications, it will be commited under source control.